# jQuery Toggle State

Tags: jquery, toggle, reset

Here's the quick and skinny of my issue:

```
$("a").toggle(function() { /*function A*/ }, function() { /*function B*/ });
```

Inside `function A` a form is displayed.  If the user successfully completes the form, the form is hidden again (returning to it's original state).

Inside `function B` the same form is hidden.

The theory behind this is that the user can choose to display the form and fill it out, or they can click again and have the form go back into hiding.

Now my question is this: currently, if the user fills out the form successfully--and it goes into hiding--the user would have to click on the link ***twice*** before returning to the toggle state that displays the form.

Is there anyway to programmatically reset the toggle switch to its initial state?

Comment: Here is tutorial on [How to create JQuery plugin to convert radio buttons into toggle buttons](http://sgeek.org/jquery-toggle-button-plugin-for-sliding-toggle-switches-sswitch/) and [Here you can see demo](http://www.demos.sgeek.org/sswitch-jquery-plugin-demo/)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

jQuery has two `.toggle()` methods:

[`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

> Toggles each of the set of matched
>   elements. If they are shown, toggle
>   makes them hidden. If they are hidden,
>   toggle makes them shown.

[`.toggle(even, odd)`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)

> Toggle between two function calls every other click.

In this case you want the first one. Something like this should do the trick:

```
$("a").click(function() {
    $("#theForm").toggle();
});
```

Comment: The even/odd syntax is removed in jQuery 1.9.  http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/

Answer (score 36):

You can check the state of the toggle in jQuery by using `.is(":hidden")`. So in basic code what I used:

```
$("#div_clicked").click(function() {
  if ($("#toggle_div").is(":hidden")) {
     // do this
  } else {
     // do that
}
}); # add missing closing
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's what I used:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#listing_position').click(function() {

    var div_form = $('#listing_position_input');
        if (div_form.hasClass('hide')) {
           div_form.removeClass('hide');
        } else {
          div_form.addClass('hide');
        }
    });  
});
```

Comment: if you just want to be toggling that one class, there's a .toggleClass() method

Answer (score 2):

Ahh, it's the simple things in life...

I was using the latter definition of `toggle(even,odd);`, but I had forgot to include in my original description of the problem that my second toggle function was not only hiding the form, but destroying it as well.

`function A`: Ajax load the form into an appended div. Hide and destroy the div on a successful form post.

`function B`: Destroy the div.

You both reminded me that `toggle();` only deals with the CSS property, and as such it is not well-suited to this task.  But then I realized that I was unnecessarily re-loading the form on each "odd" state by destroying it when I was done, so I eventually came back to this:

```
$("link").click(function() {
    if ($(this).siblings(".form-div").length == 0) {
        // form is not loaded; load and show the form; hide when done
    }
    else {
        $(this).siblings(".form-div").toggle();
    }
});
```

...which does what I want it to do.  Thanks for setting me straight about `toggle();`!

Answer (score 2):

Went with this one to avoid the additional hide/show class.
I think this is more flexible than foxy's solution as you can add more functions within but don't quote me on that i'm a noob

```
$("#clickie").click(function(){
  if ( $("#mydiv").css("display") == "none" ){
     $("#mydiv").show();
       } else {
        $("#mydiv").hide();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#div_clicked").click(function() {
  if ($("#toggle_div").is(":visible")) {
     // do this
  } else {
     // do that
}
```

Replace hidden with visible

Comment: all you did was copy another answer and you didn't even copy correctly.

Comment: @CodeMonkey However it still provides some additional information, I didn't know that one can use ":visible" :-)