# multiple instances of the same jquery script

Tags: jquery

if i have a script but it needs to run multiple times on a page, like in a cms for example, how do you approach this? in one experiment i had the code run multiple times but i put the article id on the end of the selectors that would fire off commands and what needed to be manipulated. it's not a good workaround though cause there's too much duplication of code (even though it works).

here is the example that i got help with in a recent stack overflow discussion (with the article ids appended(textpattern)):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.fullTracksInner<txp:article_id />').hide();
        $('.tracklist<txp:article_id />').click(function() {
            $('.fullTracksInner<txp:article_id />').slideToggle('medium');
            if ($('.fullTracksInner<txp:article_id />').is(':hidden')) {
                $(this).text('Show Tracklist');
            } else {
                $(this).text('Hide Tracklist');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

just imagine for example three slideshows on a page using the same slideshow script.

Comment: code beautification courtesy of http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: You may be able to generalize the script but maintain the functionality for each independently if they share a common structure or class setup.  Can we see your html?

Comment: sure, the html that is being affected looks like:

<div class="fullTracks">
<div class="fullTracksInner<txp:article_id />">
<p><txp:body /></p>
</div>
</div> <!-- end fullTracksInner class -->

<p><a href="#activity" class="tracklist<txp:article_id />">View Tracklist</a></p>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a relatively common task to do in jQuery. In order for this to work for multiple elements on the same page without requiring unique IDs, you just need to use `$(this)` in order to define the relative element you're acting on. I don't know what you're markup looks like, but you could probably do something like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.fullTracksInner<txp:article_id />').hide();

    $('.tracklist<txp:article_id />').click(function() {
     $(this).children('.fullTracksInner<txp:article_id />').slideToggle('medium');
        if ( $(this).children('.fullTracksInner<txp:article_id />').is(':hidden') ) {
            $(this).text('Show Tracklist');
        } else {
            $(this).text('Hide Tracklist');
        }
    });
});
```

*You should probably modify your selectors a little though, I would think that `$('.tracklist<txp:article_id />')` might choke in some browsers.*

Comment: thanks this looks better, by adding in more use of $this
as for the selectors, the txp:article_id thing just becomes a number after the cms parses it.

Comment: I don't fully understand how your CMS parses the code, but for your selector, I would recommend trying something like $("div[class^='tracklist']");

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the repeating code to standard JavaScript methods and then call them wherever desired.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function performSlide(tracklist) {
    var fulltracks = $('.fullTracksInner<txp:article_id />');

    $(fulltracks).slideToggle('medium');
    if (fulltracks).is(':hidden')) {
        changeText(tracklist, 'Show Tracklist');
    } else {
        changeText(tracklist, 'Hide Tracklist');
    } 
}

function changeText(textbox, text) {
    textbox.text(text);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var tracklist = $('.tracklist<txp:article_id />');

    tracklist.click(function() {
        performSlide(tracklist);
    });

    $('.someRadioButton').change(function() {
        performSlide(tracklist); 
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: thank you - this probably wouldn't get around the problem though of having to make unique IDs for every instance. i saw this thread come up on the sidebar which might be more along the lines of what i'm wondering about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082218/jquery-toggle-show-hide-w-multiple-div-ids